# Redirect a page in magento with a success message

Tags: magento, redirect, module

I am working on a custom module where i enter values and if it matches in db it redirects to home page with a message that displays on home page as blah Blah ,or if not goes to login page.
I tried the below public function with the condition as

```
if(count($alldata)==1) {
Mage::getSingleton('helloworld/helloworld')->addSuccess('my message goes here');

$this->_redirect('home');


 }else {
$this->_redirect('customer/account');
  }
```

but this gives a precces request error.

[image]

this is my whole code i added in my controller

```
 public function loginnAction()
  {
  if($this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
  $param = $this->getRequest()->getParams();


      $username = $param['fname'];
      $mobile = $param['mobileno'];


$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$table = $connectionresource->getTableName('helloworld/helloworld'); 
$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('helloworld'=>$table))->where('helloworld.mobileno=?', $mobile) 
->where('helloworld.firstname=?', $username); 
$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
 if(count($alldata)==1) {
Mage::getSingleton('helloworld/helloworld')->addSuccess('my message goes here');

$this->_redirect('home');


 }else {
$this->_redirect('customer/account');
  }

  }
  }
```

Is it not the correct format ?Or is there more i should do change?

**Updated code**

```
public function loginnAction()
  {
  if($this->getRequest()->getParams()) {
  $param = $this->getRequest()->getParams();


      $username = $param['fname'];
      $mobile = $param['mobileno'];


$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$table = $connectionresource->getTableName('helloworld/helloworld'); 
$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('helloworld'=>$table))->where('helloworld.mobileno=?', $mobile) 
->where('helloworld.firstname=?', $username); 
$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
if(count($alldata)==1) {
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('my message goes here');

$this->_redirect('home');


 }else {
$this->_redirect('customer/account');
  }

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the Magento global messaging system:

**success**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('my message goes here');
```

**error**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('my message goes here');
```

**warning**

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addWarning('my message goes here');
```

The message will be displayed in the next rendered page, if your template supports it.

Redirect or reload the user to show the message.

Comment: this goes to home page but no message is displayed

Comment: did you using the custom theme or default theme?

Comment: is cache is disabled? and check the folder var/session is created?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827283/featured-products-in-magento-home-page