# Featured products in magento home page not displaying using module

Tags: php, xml, magento, module

I want to show featured product in home page.So I Created custom module and block file in **app/code/local/FeaturedProduct/Catalog/Block/Product/Featured.php**

Code :

```
class FeaturedProduct_Catalog_Block_Product_Featured  extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{           


public function __construct()
{
    $this->setLimit(40);
    $sort_by = 'name';
    $this->setItemsPerRow(4);


    switch ($sort_by) {

        case 0:
            $this->setSortBy("rand()");
        break;
        case 1:
            $this->setSortBy("created_at desc");
        break;
        default:
            $this->setSortBy("rand()");     
    }
}

protected function _beforeToHtml()
{           
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')
            ->getProductAttributes();

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_products', 1, 'left')
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->getSelect()->order($this->getSortBy())->limit($this->getLimit());


        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

        $this->_productCollection = $collection;

    $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}

}
```

Created a configuration file in **app/code/local/FeaturedProduct/Catalog/etc/config.xml**

Code:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<config>
<modules>
<featuredproduct_catalog>
    <version>1.0.0</version>                        
</featuredproduct_catalog>
</modules>
<global>
<blocks>
    <featuredproducts>
        <class>FeaturedProduct_Catalog_Block</class>
    </featuredproducts>
</blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <featuredproducts>
            <file>featuredproduct.xml</file>
        </featuredproducts>
    </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Created featuredproducts.xml in location **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/featuredproduct.xml**

Code:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="featuredproducts/products_featured" name="featured_product_collection" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount">
                <columns>4</columns>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

Created a view file **“app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/featured.phtml”**

Code:

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>

<div class="clear"></div>  

<div class="new_product_slider">
<div id="demo">
<div class="text_left"><?php echo Mage::helper('featuredproducts')->getConfigHeading();?></div>
<div class="text_right"> <?php echo $this->__('Fragtfri ved køb over 130 kr.')?> </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="owl-demo1" class="owl-carousel">



<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
   <?php if($i > 1 ) { $j=2;} else { $j=1;} ?>

       <div class="item">
<ul>
<li>



             <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="prod"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(183, 183) ?>" width="183" height="183" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>

                  <div class="cover"
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" > <?php echo strip_tags(ucfirst($this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()))) ?></a></div>
<h4><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?></h4>
<aside class="læs_btn"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Læs mere'); ?></span></a></aside>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
                   <?php $i++; if($i%5==0) { $i=1; ?>
            <?php  } ?>


<?php  endforeach; ?>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Created a Featured Attribute in Magento Backend with yes/no property from Catalog Input Type for Store Owner dropdown, then include it in attribute set and assign one product as Featured “yes” from Catalog->Manage Products.

added this to home page cms

```
{{block type="featuredproduct/product_collection" name="product_collection" as="product_collection" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}
```

And after I load the home page it displays nothing.No idea where i have made mistake.I do not want to change local.xml so took this aproach.Is there any thing more I have to do or create other files? Please help .

**edit:**

Created module configuration file app/etc/modules/FeaturedProduct_Catalog.xml and is showing now in admin -conf-adva

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <FeaturedProduct_Catalog>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </FeaturedProduct_Catalog>
</modules>
</config>
```

Comment: did you able to see ur module in `system->configuration` tab `advanced`

Comment: post the module configuration file app/etc/modules/youfile

Comment: updated qn .. i have added conf still no results

Comment: in config.xml `<FeaturedProduct_Catalog>
    <version>1.0.0</version>                        
</FeaturedProduct_Catalog>` add like that.

Comment: did i go wrong somewhere

Comment: i have to test the you module code for that now i  see that and didn't figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Can you please test .. it would be helpful

Comment: it test there was problem with module name. so i create new module so follow it.

Comment: no idea about that..

Answer (score 0):

this is working module for featured products kindly follow it.

app/etc/modules/Solsint_Featured.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Solsint_Featured>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Solsint_Featured>
</modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Solsint/Featured/etc/config.xml

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<config>
<modules>
<Solsint_Featured>
    <version>1.0.0</version>                        
</Solsint_Featured>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <featured>
            <class>Solsint_Featured_Block</class>
        </featured>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Solsint/Featured/Block/Product/Featured.php

```
<?php 
class Solsint_Featured_Block_Product_Featured  extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{           


public function __construct()
{
    $this->setLimit(40);
    $sort_by = 'name';
    $this->setItemsPerRow(4);


    switch ($sort_by) {

        case 0:
            $this->setSortBy("rand()");
        break;
        case 1:
            $this->setSortBy("created_at desc");
        break;
        default:
            $this->setSortBy("rand()");     
    }
}

protected function _beforeToHtml()
{           
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')
            ->getProductAttributes();

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_products', 1, 'left')
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->getSelect()->order($this->getSortBy())->limit($this->getLimit());


        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

        $this->_productCollection = $collection;

    $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}

}
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/featured.phtml

```
<?php 

if ($_products = $this->getProductCollection()): ?>

<div class="clear"></div>  

<div class="new_product_slider">
<div id="demo">
<div class="text_left"><?php //echo Mage::helper('featuredproducts')->getConfigHeading();?></div>
<div class="text_right"> <?php echo $this->__('Fragtfri ved køb over 130 kr.')?> </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="owl-demo1" class="owl-carousel">



<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
   <?php if($i > 1 ) { $j=2;} else { $j=1;} ?>

       <div class="item">
<ul>
<li>



             <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="prod"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(183, 183) ?>" width="183" height="183" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>

                  <div class="cover"
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" > <?php echo strip_tags(ucfirst($this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()))) ?></a></div>
<h4><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?></h4>
<aside class="læs_btn"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Læs mere'); ?></span></a></aside>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
                   <?php $i++; if($i%5==0) { $i=1; ?>
            <?php  } ?>


<?php  endforeach; ?>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php  endif; ?>
```

cms page code

```
{{block type="featured/product_featured" name="product_collection" as="product_collection" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in

Comment: which file did you set the attribute in attribute set? and add product to featured?

Comment: dafault under general group

Comment: i have 3 featured products

Comment: magento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: remove this ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_products', 1, 'left') and check other thing working perfectly?

Comment: you have problem with your attribute. check it. also reindex the data

Comment: what can be the problem?

Comment: what about the previous question can you accept my answer there too?